# General method for solving a second order homogenous linear ODE with non constant coefficients?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

$$y'' +f(r)y' + g(r)y = 0$$

Is the form of the equation I'm given. I'm using $r$ instead of a more conventional $t$ or $x$ because it pertains to fluid dynamics with $r$ being some radius. 
I'm just wondering if I can simply use an auxiliary equation? Or is there more to it, I'm a little rusty at solving these

I don't know if it matters, but

$$f(r)= \frac {1-Re} {r}$$
and
$$g(r) = -\frac {1+Re} {r^2}$$

($Re$ is the Reynolds number).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The techniques for linear equations with non-constant coefficients of any order higher than $1$ depend quite strongly on the particular form of the coefficients. Indeed, many special functions are defined as solutions to second order linear equations with variable coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the coefficient functions does matter: in the forms you've given, you can multiply by $r^2$ to turn the equation into one of the form
$$ r^2y'' + ar y' + by = 0, $$
where $a,b$ are constants. This is called an [Euler–Cauchy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), which has a well-known form of general solution: try $y=r^m$, and you can derive a quadratic equation for $m$. With two distinct roots, this gives the general solution, $y=Ar^{m_1}+Br^{m_2}$. If the roots are the same, try $r^m \log{r}$ to find the other one. (The Wikipedia article linked explains how to arrive at these trial solutions.)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Chappers . I've heard of trying $y=e^{kx}$ as an auxiliary equation but never what you suggested, does that have a name for it? Thanks again

Comment: Also, do we assume $r^m$ is non zero, so that we can divide by it to form our quadratic?

Comment: The equation has to be true for *every* $r$, so the overall coefficient of $r^m$ must certainly be zero.

Comment: And I don't think this process has a particular name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation#Second_order_.E2.80.93_solution_through_change_of_variables shows that it's entirely equivalent to the method of substituting $y=e^{kx}$, after doing a substitution.